# Issue inheriting traits with different type parameters for a strongly typed state machine in scala

Tags: scala

I am attempting to create a state machine within the context of my current application. Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

I have defined a series of states that will grow as the application grows and a single state can transition to any number of other traits (eg. A could transition to B, C or D). I would like to be able to pattern match on all states to have the compiler warn me if I am missing any.

```
sealed trait State {
  val name: String
}

// can transition to B or C
case class StateA(data: String) extends State{
  val name = "A"
}

// can transition to C
case class StateB(data: String) extends State with BuiltFrom[StateA]{
  val name = "B"
}

/*
 *  ISSUE: class StateC inherits different type instances of trait BuiltFrom: BuiltFrom[StateB] and BuiltFrom[StateA]
 */
case class StateC(data: String) extends State with BuiltFrom[StateA] with BuiltFrom[StateB]{
  val name = "C"
}

sealed trait BuiltFrom[-State]

// Attempted to use these
// sealed trait FromA extends BuiltFrom[StateA]
// sealed trait FromB extends BuiltFrom[StateB]
```

The BuiltFrom trait I am trying to use to define what transitions are possible. It serves the purpose of allowing the compiler to stop me from defining a Transition that is invalid and to also warn me when I pattern match on the result from a transition to determine what state we are now in (instead of matching on all states I only match on the subset of possible states).

```
abstract class Transition[S <: State, V](state: S) {

  // Abstract member to define the transition
  protected def trans(s: S, v: V): BuiltFrom[S]

  // syntactical sugar
  def transition(v: V): BuiltFrom[S] = trans(state, v)

}
```

Above I have defined the transition in such a way that for any state S the only new states that can be returned have to be of type BuiltFrom[S]. I also accept some data required to make the transition (which will most often be POSTed form data).

```
case class PostedFormData(data: String)

case class TransitionA(a: StateA) extends Transition[StateA, PostedFormData](a) {

  def trans(state: StateA, formData: PostedFormData) = {
    if (formData.data.length > 0 ){ // for the sake of an example condition
      StateB(formData.data)
    }
    else{
      StateC(formData.data)
    }
  }
}
object TransitionA{

  implicit def stateAToTransitionA(s: StateA): TransitionA = TransitionA(s) // implicit conversion

}
```

Above is an example Transition. I want to be able to return a state that is of type BuiltFrom[StateA].

```
object Controller {

  // Example usage
  def action(state: StateA) = {

    val form_data = PostedFormData("Some Data")
    val new_state: BuiltFrom[StateA] = TransitionA.stateAToTransitionA(state).transition(form_data) // why will the implicit conversion not work here?

    // Extract the new state
    new_state match {
      case b: StateB => {"B"}
      case c: StateC => {"C"}
    }
  }
```

Above is how I would like to use the transition code at a controller level. Ideally the implicit conversion should work but the important thing is that I can pattern match on the states returned to determine what new state I am in.

The issue I am having is for states that can be transitioned to from multiple states. I am getting the following error:

> class StateC inherits different type instances of trait BuiltFrom: BuiltFrom[StateB] and BuiltFrom[StateA]

I would like to know if there is a way I can work around this issue. Alternatively, I am open to suggestions for a re-design that will achieve the same goals (using the compiler to my advantage as much as possible).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rather than trying to roll your own own finite state machine, you check out some of the existing options:

- [Akka FSM](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html)
- [SO Post on FSM Libraries for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875317/recommended-fsm-finite-state-machine-library-for-java)